# Integration on an exponential function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I am struggling to solve this expression.
I want to show that,
$$\frac{1}{p}\nabla_{j}\int e^{ipR\cos(\theta)} dT=i\int  \hat{p_{j}} e^{ipR\cos(\theta)} dT$$
here, $dT=d(\cos(\theta))d\phi$

I tried to solve this as below,
$$\frac{1}{p}\nabla_{j}\int e^{ipR\cos(\theta)} dT=\frac{1}{p}\int \frac{\partial}{\partial R_{j}} e^{ipR\cos(\theta)} dT$$
$$=\frac{1}{p}\int  e^{ipR\cos(\theta)}ip\cos(\theta)\frac{\partial R}{\partial R_{j}}dT$$

I know that, $\frac{\partial R}{\partial R_{j}}=\frac{R_{j}}{R}=\frac{1}{\hat{R_{j}}}$.
Thus, by applying this to the above expression yields,
$$=i\int  e^{ipR\cos(\theta)}\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\hat{R_{j}}} dT$$
However, I am not able to get $\hat{p_{j}}$ term in to the expression. As the only $p$ term inside the integration cancels out to the $\frac{1}{p}$.
Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: You need to explain your notation: what is $p$, what is $\hat{p}_j$, what does $\nabla_j$ mean, and so on.

Comment: What is p hat sub j?  You haven't defined it.

Comment: I think I already got the answer to the question. Taking $\cos(\theta)=\hat{R_{j}}\hat{p_{j}}$ would give the answer :)

Comment: $\hat{p_{j}}$ is a unit vector $\nabla _{j}=\frac{\partial }{\partial R_{j}}$

Comment: @user50724 : If you got the answer you can also write it up and post it here.